# JMSException - examples of "temporary" troubles that shouldn't trigger reinitialization?

Tags: exception, jms

Looking for experiences others might have had.  Or JMS spec citations, if you've got them.

Our typical practice when handling a JMSException (in a try/catch or onException() method) is to fully tear down the existing JMS connection/sessions/... and reinitialize them.

A developer asked if we were being too pessimistic.  Are there cases we should treat as temporary that will clear themselves?  Or is a full tear-down/reinitialize on a JMSException the best way to go?

I realize this may be somewhat vendor specific.  But any wisdom would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering my own question.  Despite *knowing* what the [JMS spec](http://java.sun.com/products/jms/docs.html) says about JMSException, I took one last look and was surprised at what I found in in the chapter on JMSException.

I saw the full list of standardized JMS exceptions under [JMSException](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/jms/JMSException.html).  And plenty of them look like bad API calls or other things not indicating any trouble requiring tear-down/reinitialization.  Like [InvalidDestinationException](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/jms/InvalidDestinationException.html) (just guessing, no experience yet).

So it sounds like a bit more fine-grained catching (not just JMSException) would allow us to distinguish conditions requiring reinitialization from not. At least in some cases.

Any further thoughts/experiences would be welcome!